# How do I stop selenium creating a new window?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This might sound like a stupid question, but I'd really appreciate any help.

I'm making a program using PyQT and Selenium. I'm using Selenium so that it can control things like getting and inputting from / to websites. However, to access the website I'll be using, 2FA is required. How can I make Selenium start not in a fresh window / profile, how can I make it keep the settings, cached passwords etc.

I'm sorry, I don't really know how to explain this, but I hope you know what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by keep the settings , what settings?

Comment: You might want to look into `DesiredCapabilities` options when creating your `driver` to set some settings from scratch. This might not accomplish exactly what you want, but I don't know of a way to attach the driver to an existing session. If this is a website your team has control over, they should implement a way for automation to bypass `2FA` in a test environment.

Comment: As in cached passwords. With most websites, 2FA has a "remember this device" option, which works of... Cookies? I'm not sure... But anyway, when selenium starts its new window, there's no settings, no cached passwords -- which makes users signing into the website via my program a nightmare, as the site uses 2FA. (@Arman)